# Let A be an $n*n$ matrix. a). suppose $A^2=0$ (zero matrix).

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, alternative-proof

> Let A be an $n*n$ matrix.
>   a). suppose $A^2=0$ (zero matrix). Prove A is not invertible.
>   b). suppose $AB=0$ for some nonzero $n*n$ matrix B. Could A be invertible?

a). proof : suppose A is invertible, then 
$A^{-1}A^{-1}AA=0*A^{-1}*A^{-1}$

then $(I_n)^2 \neq 0$

Hence not invertible.

b). suppose A is invertible,
$A^{-1}*A*B=0*A^{-1}$
$(I_n)^2*B \neq 0$

contradiction
Hence it can't.

Does this look ok? Any alternative proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part a) Your's works but here's another-
$$A^2=[0]$$
$$\det(A^2)=\det([0])$$
$$\det(A)^2=0$$
$$\det(A)=0$$
As the matrix A is singular, it is also non-invertible.

Part b) Your proof seems to have no problem and it is also how I would have done it.